# Is it possible that NSNumberFormatter leaks memory?

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks

This code leaks when I send a non-numeric string, but doesn't when I send a numeric string. Is it possible that `numberFromString:` leaks memory when failing and returning `nil`?

```
- (BOOL)isNum:(NSString*)str
{
    BOOL ans = YES;
    NSNumberFormatter* nf = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    if ([nf numberFromString:str] == nil)
        ans = NO;
    [nf release];
    return ans;
}
```

Comment: What makes you think that it leaks?

Comment: I'm using Instruments. It says this code leaks 16 bytes.

Comment: Just tested it with @"jsdfklsjdf" and doesn't leak a single byte. Maybe show more context. Maybe see what objects are leaking, maybe your string?

Comment: As no context is given... *Maybe* the formatter uses some autoreleased objects itself, so make sure there is actually an autorelease pool in place that gets drained (in case of some threading, looping etc.).

Comment: It appears that when I send a hardcoded string (i.e @"asd") it works fine, but when I send an NSString variable it leaks. Oh well, thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. It is fine when the parameter only containing letters, such as `@"asdf"` or only containing numbers, such as `@"1234"`. It will leak, as the Instruments shown, when the parameter is the combination of letters and numbers, such as `@"123asdf"`.